# Initial Installation Trouble

Tags: boot

I replaced Windows 7 on a circa 2007 HP desktop with a recent version of Ubuntu that I could boot from the DVD drive. (The BIOS doesn't give me an option to boot from a USB drive) That worked fine. Then I removed the two hard drives and installed a new hard drive. I reinstalled Ubuntu from the DVD drive. When the installation finishes and it restarts and has me remove the DVD, I get a grub rescue error message Attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0. What is the solution to this?

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product or release details. What Ubuntu system did you install? Ubuntu Core 20? Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop? etc.  In my experience a "*attempt to read or write outside*" is the result of corrupted data, but it's not clear where you are; most ISOs request you to remove installation media & reboot yet you show a different order for your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release.  It may also help if you're specific with details (eg. your ~2007 PC for example; my last QA install was to a "*hp dc7700*" which is pre-2007; being specific helps)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's a flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 that would fit on a DVD. I got the problem resolved last night just by changing the hard drive control from IDE to ACHI. The error message doesn't appear and Ubuntu boots normally.